# Python function to build list from a text file

Tags: python, list, text-files

For my homework assignment I need to write the body of this function, using the comments as my requirements. The other functions mentioned in the comments have been provided to me:

```
def eventfreq(year,month):

'''
  Read DOT1000.txt and return a list of (d,ct)
  pairs, where d is a date object of the form
     datetime.date(A,B,C)
  having A equal to the year argument and 
  B equal to the month argument to eventfreq(year,month).
  The ct part of each pair is the number of records 
  that had a date equal to datetime.date(A,B,C).

  One more requirement:  sort the returned list 
  in increasing order by date (the sorted function will
  do this for you)

  Use fieldict("DOT1000.txt") to get the dictionary
  of tuples used for building the list of pairs
  that eventfreq(year,month) will return.
  '''
```

This is my effort:

```
def eventfreq(year, month):
    N=fieldict('DOT1000.txt')[line][1]
    L = []  # empty List for accumulation
    for line in N:  # data file is standard input 

               st = N[1] # get datetime.date 
               (L[st] = L.get(st,0) + 1)
```

Comment: I can warn you now that this will be downvoted, try to be more specific about what aspect of the question you are struggling with

Comment: I cleaned up your question; but @COpython is correct, you need to ask a specific question. For example, _"I understand how to call the function and loop through the results, but I'm not sure how to do ____. I tried it this way _____, but I got this error _____"_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to check this:

```
def eventfreq(year, month):
    dates = [dt for x, dt, y in fieldict('DOT1000.txt') if dt.year==year and dt.month==month]
    return [(dt, dates.count(dt)) for dt in set(dates)
```